# Validation not working with React Datepicker and Formik

Tags: reactjs, validation, formik, react-datepicker

I have been working on a form and been using Formik. For some reason all the props like errors and values are being passed but touched is not working. I am assuming that touched is not properly set up but I am unsure what would be causing it. I currently have this:

```
<Formik
 initialValues={{date: ''}}
 validation={{date: Yup.string().required('some error')}}
 onSubmit={(values) => { console.log(values) }}
>
 {({ errors, touched, values, setFieldValue }) => {
  <form onSubmit={handleSubmit}>
   ...
   <DatePicker 
    id="date" 
    name="date" 
    value={values.date}
    errors={errors.date}
    touched={touched.date} 
    onChange={setFieldValue}
   />
   <button type='submit'>Submit</button>
  </form>
 }}
</Formik>
```

I have been checking the prop values being sent in and the only thing that is not working is touched as it is undefined. Did I configure the date picker incorrectly here? I am getting everything else and I am able to set the value but touched is never set. I have other fields similar to this as well but is working fine. What could be causing this issue?

Comment: Are you getting the `is-invalid` class put on your input control when the DatePicker fails validation? I'm not, with this syntax.

Answer (score 1):

I managed to fix this by passing the handleBlur handler to the DatePicker component

```
 onBlur={handleBlur}
```